# $_POST is empty after form submit

Tags: php, html

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to build a web application. I have a form where user should enter his name and last name and click submit. The problem is, that the `$_POST` comes back empty.
I am using WAMP on Windows 8 machine.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["send"])) {
    print_r($_POST)
} else {
    ?>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
        <div class="control-group"> <!-- Firstname -->
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">First name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group"> <!-- Lastname -->
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">last name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputLastname" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit data</button>
            <a href="<?php $mywebpage->goback(); ?>" class="btn">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add names to the input types like

```
<input type="text" id="inputLastname" name="inputLastname" placeholder="Last name">
```

Now check the `$_POST` variable.

Answer (score 9):

Your inputs don't have `name` attributes. Set those:

```
<input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="First name" name="first_name" />
<input type="text" id="inputLastname" placeholder="Last name" name="last_name" >
```

Also, look at the way you detect a form submission:

```
if(isset($_POST['send']))
```

You check if the submit button is present in the post data. This is a bad idea because in the case of Internet Explorer, the submit button won't be present in the post data if the user presses the enter key to submit the form.

A better method is:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Or

```
if(isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name']))
```

More info - [`Why isset($_POST['submit'])` is bad](http://www.crosscode.co.uk/php/why-using-isset-post-submit-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer/).

Answer (score 0):

I have notice that using '**name**' attribute doesn't work well with **Bootstrap Validator** for (if(isset($_POST["send"]))).So in case if you like to add validation on your form then I recommend you to follow this way!

**Solution**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit data</button>
```

php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're checking if `$_POST['send']` is set, but it won't be. The "send" field in your form is the button, but the button doesn't have a value, so it won't be included in `$_POST`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["send"])) {
  echo $_POST["inputName"];
    echo $_POST["inputLastname"];
} 
else {
    ?>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <div class="control-group"> <!-- Firstname -->
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">First name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="First name" name="inputName"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group"> <!-- Lastname -->
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">last name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputLastname" name="inputLastname" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit data</button>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add the location of the file in action or use:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: 1. The action can be added through javascript. 2. Please don't advice to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`