# jquery unable to change hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass data from the main page into a modal based on what button on the main page the user clicks. So I am trying to use jquery to change a hidden input field within a form on the modal. But it is not working and I have no idea why.

So this is the button that is supposed to make the change:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="javascript:$('#DomainName').val('example.com');">example.com</button>
```

The form within the modal looks like this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="DomainName" value="" />
    <button type="submit" id="confirm" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

But when I test this on my local server, test.php displays nothing. It's code is:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['DomainName'];
?>
```

I'm sure it's something simple I am missing but not seeing. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\_POST is empty after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109603/post-is-empty-after-form-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input needs `name="DomainName"`

Comment: Ok I see it needs both id and name, for some reason I thought it only needed id. Thanks.  I'd accept your answer now but I have to wait for some arbitrary reason.

Comment: Form inputs need the name to submit data to the server. They don't actually need an ID, that just makes it easier to target the input with JS (or CSS) - it's completely optional.