# jQuery not all form data is being sent to $_POST

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to send data to a backend using jQuery. If I console log the formdata then I see 9 fields with their values. But in the php page that is supposed to receive the data I only see 3 fields when doing a var_dump. There is no other code on the php page.

Here is my jQuery ajax call:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#disputeReturnBtn", function () {
        if ($("#rrn").val() == "") {
            alert("RRN cannot be empty");
        }
        if (!$("input[name='dispute']:checked").val()) {
            alert("Please choose a step");
        }
        var disputeform = document.getElementById("disputeForm");
        var formData = new FormData(disputeform);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../form/scans.php",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                disputeform.reset();
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
        });
    });
```

Why am I only see the data of three fields when the formdata has 9 fields? Cause the data is not being inserted into the database because not all the fields are there.

Is my ajax call wrong?

Here is the html form:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: ../login.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo $_SESSION['company']; ?> Scans</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/scans.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        0
    </script>
    <div class="horizontal" id="topRow">
        <div class="appTitle">
            <h1><?php if (isset($_SESSION['company'])) {
                    echo $_SESSION['company'];
                } ?> Scans</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="userName flex">
            <p>Logged in as</p>
            <h3><?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
                    echo $_SESSION['name'];
                } else {
                    echo "Nobody";
                }
                ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="logoutBtn">
            <form action="../logout.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="logoutBtn" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productScan">
        <div class="uploadForm">
            <form action="" method="POST" id="disputeForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p class="small">Enter the RRN number and wait 5 seconds for the app to search the database.</p>
                <fieldset class="rrnLabel flex">
                    <label for="rrn">RRN Label <span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="rrn" id="rrn" required />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="returnDate flex">
                    <label for="returndate">Return date</label>
                    <input type="text" id="returndate" value="" placeholder="Item found" disabled>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="userComments flex">
                    <label for="usercomments">User comments</label>
                    <textarea type="text" name="user_comments" id="usercomments" value="" placeholder="Comments" disabled></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="returnReason flex">
                    <label for="returnreason">Return reason</label>
                    <textarea type="text" id="returnreason" , value="" placeholder="Reason for return" disabled></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="explainProcess">
                        <p>Take a clear picture of the item from all sides.</p>
                        <ul id="todoList">
                            <li>Photo 1: Photo of product</li>
                            <li>Photo 2: Clear Photo of RRN Label</li>
                            <li>Photo 3: Clear Photo of S-Label</li>
                            <li>Photo 4: Clear Photo of Bar Code</li>
                            <li>Photo 5: Clear Photo of Damage</li>
                            <li>Photo 6: Clear Photo of Damage</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <!-- PhotoS -->
                <div class="fieldsetWrap horizontal">
                    <fieldset class="fileInput relative">
                        <h4>Product Photo<span>*</span></h4>
                        <input type="file" ref='file' name="product_photo" id="product_photo" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp, image/bmp" />
                        <div class="button absolute">Choose File</div>
                        <div class="previewImage">
                            <img id="product_photoImg" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="fileInput relative">
                        <h4>RRN Label Photo<span>*</span></h4>
                        <input type="file" ref='file' name="rrn_photo" id="rrn_photo" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp, image/bmp" />
                        <div class="button absolute">Choose File</div>
                        <div class="previewImage">
                            <img id="rrn_photoImg" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="fileInput relative">
                        <h4>S-Label Photo</h4>
                        <input type="file" ref='file' name="slabel_photo " id="slabel_photo" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp, image/bmp" />
                        <div class="button absolute">Choose File</div>
                        <div class="previewImage">
                            <img id="slabel_photoImg" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="fileInput relative">
                        <h4>Bar Code Photo</h4>
                        <input type="file" ref='file' name="barcode_photo " id="barcode_photo" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp, image/bmp" />
                        <div class="button absolute">Choose File</div>
                        <div class="previewImage">
                            <img id="barcode_photoImg" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="fileInput relative">
                        <h4>Photo 5</h4>
                        <input type="file" ref='file' name="photo_5" id="photo_5" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp, image/bmp" />
                        <div class="button absolute">Choose File</div>
                        <div class="previewImage">
                            <img id="photo_5Img" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="fileInput relative">
                        <h4>Photo 6</h4>
                        <input type="file" ref='file' name="photo_6" id="photo_6" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg, image/webp, image/bmp" />
                        <div class="button absolute">Choose File</div>
                        <div class="previewImage">
                            <img id="photo_6Img" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <fieldset class="disputeSteps">
                    <h3>Next steps with regards to this returned product <span>*</span></h3>
                    <fieldgroup class="checkboxes">
                        <ul id="disputeSteps">
                            <li><input type="radio" name="dispute" id="dispute" value="yes" required>
                                <p for="disputeReturn">Dispute return with company</p>
                            </li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="dispute" id="nodispute" value="no">
                                <p for="noDispute">No need to dispute</p>
                            </li>
                            <li><input type="radio" name="dispute" id="other" value="other">
                                <p for="disputeOther">Other</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </fieldgroup>
                    <label for="warehouse_comments">Reason for Dispute</label>
                    <textarea name="warehouse_comments" id="warehouse_comments" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Please provide your comments"></textarea>
                    <button type="button" id="disputeReturnBtn">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../assets/js/scans.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

Here is the form data I see in the console:

```
FormData(9) { rrn → "RRN-BZYJJ-VAYX", product_photo → {}, rrn_photo → {}, "slabel_photo " → {}, "barcode_photo " → {}, photo_5 → {}, photo_6 → {}, dispute → "yes", warehouse_comments → "Nothing wrong" }
​
<entries>
​​
0: rrn → "RRN-BZYJJ-VAYX"
​​
1: product_photo → File { name: "167236-004-AE764A76.jpg", lastModified: 1530003296000, size: 38057, … }
​​
2: rrn_photo → File { name: "39342221_884539318417339_7097049967600074752_n.jpg", lastModified: 1534602632000, size: 50778, … }
​​
3: "slabel_photo " → File { name: "Beer.jpg", lastModified: 1585846680000, size: 75259, … }
​​
4: "barcode_photo " → File { name: "48361261_2187373174923474_3499519716190322688_n.jpg", lastModified: 1544863424000, size: 117241, … }
​​
5: photo_5 → File { lastModified: 1674156665588, size: 0, type: "application/octet-stream", … }
​​
6: photo_6 → File { lastModified: 1674156665588, size: 0, type: "application/octet-stream", … }
​​
7: dispute → "yes"
​​
8: warehouse_comments → "Nothing wrong"
​
<prototype>: FormDataPrototype { append: append(), delete: delete(), get: get(), … }
```

Here is the response I get from the var_dump($_POST) in the pphp file scans.php:

```
array(3) {
  ["rrn"]=>
  string(5) "sdfds"
  ["dispute"]=>
  string(2) "no"
  ["warehouse_comments"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Please add **all** pertinent code - the form, the PHP and Javascript.

Comment: side note: calling `header("Location: ...")` will not stop the script. All code after is executed. Don't forget to stop the script using `exit;` just after `header('Location')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\_POST is empty after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109603/post-is-empty-after-form-submit)

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 0

Many of you inputs have an `id` attribute, but no `name` attribute. AFAIK, they need a `name` attribute to show up in a POST.

For instance, replace:

```html
<input type="text" id="returndate" value="" placeholder="Item found" disabled>
```

with:

```html
<input type="text" name="returndate" id="returndate" value="" placeholder="Item found" disabled>
```

### Problem 1

Note that the files uploaded do not show up in `$_POST`, they instead show up in `$_FILES` and are dealt with differently in PHP.

### Further debugging

Also, try opening up the network trace for the POST it makes using the [browser's developer tools](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=browser+network+trace&ia=web). Usually opened by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> then going to the Network tab.